# Laravel: Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed

Tags: php, json, database, laravel

I'm trying to upload an image, store it on disk and add the path to a JSON file that is stored on the database. 
every user got a JSON file with all his images like:

```
{"images": ["/vendors/57/horse-11.png", "/vendors/57/horse-11.png"]}
```

That JSON file is stored in the database in the 'images' column.

I'm struggling with this issue for days.. I always get following exception:

```
Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed
```

the error occurs in this part of the code from the processImage function:

```
$image = Image::make($request->file('image'))
                ->resize(750, null, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })
                ->encode('png');
```

I will guide you through the proces:

first the user uploads an image, code:

https://codeshare.io/jGzQ9

secondly, via the routes.php a controller is called:

```
public function update(User $user, UserHouse $house, UserHouseRequest $request){
    $path = $this->processImage($request, $user->id, $house->id);
    $jsonstring = $house->images;
    array_push($jsonstring['images'], $path);

    $house->images = $jsonstring;
    $house->save();

    return back();
}

private function processImage($request, $userId, $houseId)
{
    $path = null;
    $number = rand(1, 99);
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = Image::make($request->file('image'))
            ->resize(750, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })
            ->encode('png');
        $path = "/users/{$userId}/house-{$houseId}-{$number}.png";
        Storage::disk('fileadmin')->put($path, $image->encoded);
    }

    return $path;
}
```

There is also some JS code, but I think that that isn't necessary for this problem. If it does, I will add it later.

I'm using Laravel 5.5

stacktrace:

```
2019-05-28 13:30:49] local.ERROR: Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed {"userId":57,"email":"info@ho.com","exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Serialization of 'Illuminate\\Http\\UploadedFile' is not allowed at /Users/sg/ah-website/user/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php:128)
[stacktrace]
#0 /Users/sg/website/user/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php(128): serialize(Array)
#1 /Users/sg/website/user/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(87): Illuminate\\Session\\Store->save()
#2 /Users/sg/website/user/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(218): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->terminate(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Response))
#3 /Users/sg/website/user/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(189): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminateMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Response))
#4 /Users/sg/website/public/index.php(60): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminate(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Response))
#5 /Users/sg/website/server.php(21): require_once('/Users/sg...')
#6 {main}
"}
```

config/filesystems.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
    | reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
    | will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
    |
    */

    'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "s3", "rackspace"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],

        'fileadmin' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path(),
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'url' => config('app.url'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: Can you share the full error message, complete with error line and stack trace, if possible?

Comment: @aynber sure,I will add it to the original question

Comment: The error isn't in this code. It's probably somewhere in your middleware when it's trying to save data to the session.

Comment: @aynber any idea where I need to look?

Comment: have you tried using other redirection than `return back()` ?

Comment: @N69S, Yes to another view, same error..

Comment: This one's a bit tricky to trace, especially since the trace mostly references src files. You can check inside of server.php and index.php, and any custom middleware you're using. Look specifically for anything being stored into the session.

Comment: The error occurs in the part when the file is stored on the disk. I checked it with dd('test')"s. I added that to the question

Comment: Can you show your `config/filesystems.php`, specifically the `fileadmin` section?

Comment: @aynber I added it to the code

Comment: Hmm, no cache bits there, so yeah, at a loss here. Sorry!

Comment: @aynber what do you mean? :)

Comment: Some filesystems have caching (https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#caching), but yours doesn't so that's not what was affecting it. So other than tracing through the src files, I'm really not sure where to go from here.